# Customise RTLCSS config for VS Web Essentials 2013

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, right-to-left, web-essentials, rtlcss

Visual Studio Web Essentials has the ability to auto-generate a Right-To-Left variant for CSS files.

[image]

This will automatically change CSS properties such as `padding-left` to `padding-right`.

However it also does other things such as changing file names from "right.png" to "left.png".

Web Essentials uses [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) to do this which I know can be configured to turn some of these features off.

[image]

There is no obvious option in Visual Studio to be able to config RTLCSS through Web Essentials.

I know that Web Essentials is consuming RTLCSS via NodeJS using the following file:

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions{webessentials}\Resources\nodejs\tools\server\services\srv-rtlcss.js

I could update the following line in this file to add custom options, however this would be specific to my machine and not the MVC solution I'm using:

```
var config = configLoader.load(null, path.dirname(sourceFileName), { options: { minify: false } });
```

**Is there a way I can configure RTLCSS for Web Essentials specifically for my MVC Solution?**

For example I know Web Essentials allows Solution specific settings via a `WebEssentials-Settings.json` file. Can I customise this file to use a version of the `srv-rtlcss.js` file which I could include in my MVC solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration can be set using one of the following methods:

- Put your config into your projects `package.json` file under the `rtlcssConfig` property.
- Use a special file `.rtlcssrc` or `.rtlcssrc.json`

To edit the global RTLCSS settings, open web essentials menu then select "Edit global RTLCSS settings (.rtlcssrc)"

[image]

This will create the default configuration for you and place it in `C:\Users\{username}`, To make these settings local, create a copy of `.rtlcssrc` and place it in your project.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after, how can I ensure my solution will look at the version in my project?

Comment: @Curt config loader starts with the current directory all the way up to the home folder. so if it's found in your project folder, that version will be used.

Comment: Perfect! Will test this out and approve. Cheers.